# RMarkdown Word custom-style for rchunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

It would be great if anyone knows how to manually set the style (custom-style) for r-chunk.
I know that for text part, we could use

```
::: {custom-style="Poetry"}

| A Bird came down the Walk---

| He did not know I saw---

:::
```

to manually set the style for above two lines as "Poetry". (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles) Then we could modify the style "Poetry" in the reference word document.

How about rchunk part?
I tried

```
{r , custom-style="Poetry"}
```

but did not work.

Comment: Do you want to see a code chunk in "poetry" style?

Answer (score 0):

Run your code chunk and see what style the output is assigned to in Word. Then, modify that style in your reference word document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But some r chunks share the same style, while I would like to set different layout for different r chunks. So I would like to know how to manually set the style for r chunk. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar effect with the officedown and officer packages:

```
---
```

### title: "Example"
output:
officedown::rdocx_document

```
library(officedown)
library(officer)
```

### Text1

```
properties1 <- fp_text(color = "red", bold = TRUE, font.size = 50)

text1 <- 'Is this the real life?'

ftext(text1, properties1)
```

### Text2

```
properties2 <- fp_text(color = "blue", italic = TRUE, font.size = 20)

text2 <- 'Is this just fantasy?'

ftext(text2, properties2)
```

Has an extra benefit if you keep swapping between a few styles, rather than defining them each time.